# the measurability of function with respect to the strong limit of signed measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu_n$ be a sequence of finite signed Radon measure on $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ open bounded, and a function $g\geq 1$ such that $g$ is measurable with respect $\mu_n$ for each $n$.

Define $\nu_n:=g\mu_n$. Assume that each $\nu_n$ is still a finite radon measure and $\nu_n\to \nu$ for some finite signed Radon measure $\nu$ in strong sense, i.e., the total variation $|\nu_n - \nu|(\Omega)$ goes to $0$.

My question: do I have $g$ is measurable with respect to $\nu$? I want to make definition of measure $\mu_0:=\frac{1}{g}\nu$ to make sense.

---

My try: let $B\subset \mathbb R^1$ be open and we define $B_g:=g^{-1}(B)$. I need to prove that $B_g$ is $\nu$ measurable. We know $B_g$ is of course $\mu_n$ measurable, and hence $g\mu_n$ measurable.

why $B_g$ is $g\mu_n$ measurable? b/c $g\mu_n(B_g)<\infty$.

Then I have $B_g$ is $\nu$ measurable since $\nu(B_g)<\infty$ by strong convergence.

I am not really sure my argument makes sense...Any help is really welcome!